# Criar diretório e adicionar arquivos para consultar posteriormente no android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Sou novo na área de desenv. mobile, estou desenvolvendo um app simples que utiliza  a biblioteca [Tesseract-OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr) no Android Studio  e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Preciso armazenar alguns arquivos no android p/ consulta-los posteriormente.

- Como e em que momento eu gravo esses arquivos no android?
- Após criar esse diretório com os arquivos, como obtenho o caminho?

Comment: Nunca precisei usar, mas veja aqui esse tutorial se ajuda: http://www.codepool.biz/making-an-android-ocr-application-with-tesseract.html

Comment: @AckLay Vou dar uma olhada, mas to pesquisando bastante já sobre como usar o tesseract no windows com android-studio, na grande maioria dos tutoriais é em linux e eclipse, já consegui avançar bastante, já estou conseguindo usar o tesseract, falta umas últimas configurações, calibrar etc... A funcionalidade principal já funciona, o problema é que adicionei esses arquivos que preciso no sdcard manualmente, por isso a pergunta, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para armazenar diversos tipos de arquivos como por exemplo .txt, .json, etc, você primeiro precisa criar uma **Assets folder**, é la que você vai colocar seus arquiovos.

---

para Criar uma **Assets Folder** é só clicar no seu projéto com o botão direito do mouse e seguir este caminho:

**New->Folder->Assets Folder**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Agora que tem uma **Assets Folder** é só entrar nela e arrastar os arquivos que deseja. Para entrar nela basta seguir as orientações da próxima imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Agora seu arquivo já aparece no projéto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Para ler o arquivo, você pode fazer desta forma:

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset(String nomeArquivo) {
String json = null;
try {
    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(nomeArquivo);
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();
    String texto = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}

return texto;
}
```

---

Comment: Assim que possível vou testar, posto o feedback aqui, caso funcione aceito a resp, muito obrigado desde já.

Comment: Desculpe, mas o que isso tem a ver com a biblioteca Tesseract-OCR ?

Comment: @AckLay O autor da pergunta não pediu informações de como usar o Tesseract, mas sim de como salvar dados em uma pasta, o que já foi respondido.

Comment: @Luc , me desculpe, eu falei que a resposta está errada?

Comment: Calma galera, ta tudo certo, @AckLay não disse em momento algum que estava errada, só perguntou o que tinha a ver. O Luc respondeu simplesmente de uma forma bem direta, enfim, obrigado a todos os envolvidos, funcionou aqui.E a propósito Ack Lay, to pensando em criar uma pergunta sobre como configurar e usar o tesseract detalhadamente aqui no stackoverflow com recompensa, só vou pensar em uma forma p/ não ficar muito abrangente, tu acha que se encaixa no escopo do stack?

Comment: @AckLay, nope. Não foi isso que quis dizer. Foi porque tua pergunta parecia dizer que o autor da pergunta tinha perguntado sobre o Tesseract...

Comment: @Mathias tem sim, pode perguntar! :)

Answer (score 1):

Puxa, me ajudou muito. Eu estava tentando criar uma pasta normal e jogar os arquivos lá dentro. Daí o InputStream sempre retornava null. Daí, criando esta pasta assets, deu certinho. Minha ideia é colocar nela várias figuras e recuperar dinamicamente  com base em um objeto. Veja com ficou:

```
if(!(questao.getImagem()==null || questao.getImagem().isEmpty())){
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = context.getAssets().open(questao.getImagem());//"vestibular1questao5.jpeg");
                imagemQuestao.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(is, ""));
                imagemQuestao.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                imagemQuestao.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```